# How to define the context for a Docker build as a specific commit on one of the local branches?

Tags: git, docker

I'd like to provide the context for a Docker build command using a commit hash referring the local repository.

Docs covering Docker build specify how to refer a branch or a tag on a remote repository but not on the local. [Reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#git-repositories)

I tried substituting the URL with `file://` protocol to refer the local git repository but that returns an error

`docker build file:///home/username/repositories/hello-world`

Error

> unable to prepare context: path
>   "file:///home/username/repositories/hello-world" not found

I'd like to refer the local Git repository (a specific commit, tag or branch) as the build context for Docker to build the image.

I've had a look at this question [Docker build specific local git branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56793996/docker-build-specific-local-git-branch) but I'd prefer not to have to clone or checkout the branch to build from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I confirm that the `file://` url prefix is not recognized as a (Git) URL by `docker build`.

The relevant code fragment is [that one](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/bba833928cd7be404cfd6931c90b7e8f0401a594/pkg/urlutil/urlutil.go#L11-L22):

```
validPrefixes = map[string][]string{
    "url": {"http://", "https://"},

    // The github.com/ prefix is a special case used to treat context-paths
    // starting with `github.com` as a git URL if the given path does not
    // exist locally. The "github.com/" prefix is kept for backward compatibility,
    // and is a legacy feature.
    //
    // Going forward, no additional prefixes should be added, and users should
    // be encouraged to use explicit URLs (https://github.com/user/repo.git) instead.
    "git": {"git://", "github.com/", "git@"},

    […]
```

On the one hand, `git clone` supports both `git clone /home/path/repo.git` and `git clone file:///home/path/repo.git` − and actually behaves differently between the two syntaxes, given that the former implies the [`--local` flag](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---local) (as an aside, I use here the wording `repo.git` instead of `repo/.git`, as I assume for simplicity that this `repo.git` is a [bare repo](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init#Documentation/git-init.txt---bare), i.e., with no checked-out working directory).

So you may want to open a feature request on `moby` to support `docker build file:///home/path/repo.git` (which would trigger `git clone file:///home/path/repo.git`) so that we could even specify something like `docker build file:///home/path/repo.git#master:folder/subfolder`.

On the other hand, you can already emulate this feature in an efficient way by relying on the ["STDIN mode" of `docker build`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#build-with--), combined with some [Bash process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) and with [`git archive`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive) (which does not modify the repo itself, so it should address your requirement of doing no checkout of the branch):

```
docker build -t image - < <(cd /home/path/repo.git && \
  git archive --format=tar.gz master:folder/subfolder)
```

In this case, note that the `Dockerfile` that will be considered is that of the Git repo, in branch `master` under path `folder/subfolder`.

Actually, the "redirection + process substitution" `… < <(…)` is unneeded and can be replaced with a mere pipe:

```
cd /home/path/repo.git && \
git archive --format=tar.gz master:folder/subfolder | docker build -t image -
```

(and you can remove the `:folder/subfolder` part if your `Dockerfile` is at the root of the repo)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response and the links. I'm not very familiar with the Bash process substitution and git archive commands. I'll run these and confirm your answer accordingly.

Comment: @dsinecos the process substitution was actually unneeded :) so I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @dsinecos do you confirm the proposed solution works for you? (if yes, feel free to vote or mark the answer as accepted)

Comment: Sorry, I haven't had the chance to try out this solution yet and so haven't confirmed the answer. I used a different workaround for the problem I was facing than pulling from a specific commit on the local repository. I plan to try out your solution over the coming weekend and will confirm the answer then

Comment: I tried it out and it works like a charm. Thanks again :)